# Weblogic and Glassfish Jax-RS Jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jax-rs, glassfish-3

there is a problem with webservices libs. The log which is belong to Glassfish's shown below:

```
|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError
```

Unfortunately, I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you moved some of the jars from WLS to GF. If so, remove the `com.sun.jersey.server_*.jar` that was moved from WLS from your GF installation (or from your WAR if it's there) and you should be fine. You don't need this jar to run your JAX-RS service in GF 3.1.2 (GF should have all needed dependencies bundled in it).

Comment: I think you mean that there are jars in my lib so that they need weblogic specific libs?

Comment: Oh, my bad - do you have `jersey-servlet.jar` in your WAR or in GF installation? If so can you take a look what's inside `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` in this jar?

Comment: I have found the jar file which is com.sun.jersey.server_1.1.0.0_1-9.jar in the war then I removed it, It looks ok. thanks

Comment: Did you move this file from your WLS installation or was it a part of your WAR? (I am trying to figure out how this file got to GF)

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE, There is a lib folder in the project, there are third party jars in the lib, so that I found the com.sun.jersey.server_1.1.0.0_1-9.jar in the lib , I checked META-INF/services I see *.ServletContainerInitializer then I removed this jar file.